# Why is it possible to store a str value on a int type variable on Python using typing

Tags: python, python-3.x, types, typing

I come from a java background and i'm starting with python 3.x and types.
In java it's not possible to do something like this:

```
num:int = 5;
name:str = num
num = "hola"

print(type(num)) # <class 'int'>
```

The interpreter doesn't complain when storing an int value in a str variable or viceversa.

I didn't find any example of using this *var_name: type_name = 5* kind of asignations in python's official 3.6.7 docs, but, again, the interpreter think it's ok.

**Why is this possible?**

Comment: Briefly: Python has strong but dynamic typing. Type hints are just hints and don't actually enforce anything.

Comment: Variables in Python don't need explicit declarations to reserve memory space.